# I can't stream nor play normally

Tags: command-line, 20.04, graphics, streaming, obs-studio

Okay, I'm aware there are hundreds of other questions like this one out there and I've read a bunch of them, but the solutions were so specific to each individual case that I just must ask for help.
I'm a kinda new user of Ubuntu 20.04, in the sense that I've had it long enough to know how it should behave but not enough to actually know how to fix it when it doesn't.

So, summarizing, I had issues with my internet and after a lot of trial and error I reached the conclusion that I should format everything and reinstall the OS; so I did. Now my internet is fine, hooray! But at some point, while I was customizing everything to my liking and installing programs, I tried streaming on OBS (something I did before with no issues) and I found it got LAGGY. Oh no. Anyway, I forgot about it for a while after not finding any help online and I tried to play The Sims 4 (which I've always done, for hours) and again, almost as if I had a shitty computer who couldn't hold it.
Thinking about it now, I should've been writing down somewhere which specific codes I input into the terminal just in case this happened.

I really don't know what to do or what to copy-paste into the terminal so I could give you the info you need to lend me a hand, so if any candid soul could guide me through this process it would be fantastic.

My About page says:

- Memory: 15,6 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-9600K CPU @ 3.70GHz × 6
- Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030]
- Disk Capacity: 6,3 TB
- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS OS
- Type: 64-bit
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11

EDIT: I found online there's a file that shows a history of the changes one has done to the computer. I don't know if all of them are, but here goes nothing:

```
Start-Date: 2022-03-01  10:04:07
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-01  10:04:09

Start-Date: 2022-03-01  10:04:12
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 (0.105-26ubuntu1.2, 0.105-26ubuntu1.3), libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-26ubuntu1.2, 0.105-26ubuntu1.3), policykit-1:amd64 (0.105-26ubuntu1.2, 0.105-26ubuntu1.3), gir1.2-polkit-1.0:amd64 (0.105-26ubuntu1.2, 0.105-26ubuntu1.3)
End-Date: 2022-03-01  10:04:15

Start-Date: 2022-03-01  10:04:18
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.34.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.34.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-01  10:04:18

Start-Date: 2022-03-01  17:08:23
Commandline: apt install ppa-purge
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: ppa-purge:amd64 (0.2.8+bzr63)
End-Date: 2022-03-01  17:08:25

Start-Date: 2022-03-01  19:04:34
Commandline: packagekit role='install-packages'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libx265-179:i386 (3.2.1-1build1, automatic), libwebp6:i386 (0.6.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libusb-1.0-0:i386 (2:1.0.23-2build1, automatic), libkrb5-3:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1, automatic), libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1, automatic), libsnappy1v5:i386 (1.1.8-1build1, automatic), libopenjp2-7:i386 (2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1, automatic), libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (1.44.7-2ubuntu4, automatic), libaa1:i386 (1.4p5-46, automatic), libnghttp2-14:i386 (1.40.0-1build1, automatic), libgphoto2-port12:i386 (2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libraw1394-11:i386 (2.1.2-1, automatic), libieee1284-3:i386 (0.2.11-13build1, automatic), libcom-err2:i386 (1.45.5-2ubuntu1, automatic), libcups2:i386 (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1, automatic), libwayland-egl1:i386 (1.18.0-1, automatic), libdbus-1-3:i386 (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1, automatic), libwind0-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), netpbm:amd64 (2:10.0-15.3build1, automatic), jq:amd64 (1.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libsasl2-modules-db:i386 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), libvkd3d1:i386 (1.1-4, automatic), libldap-2.4-2:i386 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8, automatic), libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4, automatic), libdv4:i386 (1.0.0-12, automatic), libgphoto2-6:i386 (2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2, automatic), libproxy1v5:i386 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2, automatic), libssh-4:i386 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2, automatic), liblcms2-2:i386 (2.9-4, automatic), imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4, automatic), libcairo-gobject2:i386 (1.16.0-4ubuntu1, automatic), libopenal1:i386 (1:1.19.1-1, automatic), va-driver-all:i386 (2.7.0-2, automatic), libswresample3:i386 (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libcdparanoia0:i386 (3.10.2+debian-13, automatic), p7zip:amd64 (16.02+dfsg-7build1, automatic), libbrotli1:i386 (1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1, automatic), libsystemd0:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb, automatic), glib-networking:i386 (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libsndio7.0:i386 (1.5.0-3, automatic), libgd3:i386 (2.2.5-5.2ubuntu2.1, automatic), libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libshout3:i386 (2.4.3-1, automatic), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libpsl5:i386 (0.21.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), libpixman-1-0:i386 (0.38.4-0ubuntu1, automatic), libmount1:i386 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3, automatic), libsqlite3-0:i386 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2, automatic), liborc-0.4-0:i386 (1:0.4.31-1, automatic), librsvg2-common:i386 (2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libxrender1:i386 (1:0.9.10-1, automatic), libbz2-1.0:i386 (1.0.8-2, automatic), libicu66:i386 (66.1-2ubuntu2.1, automatic), libmagickwand-6.q16-6:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4, automatic), libogg0:i386 (1.3.4-0ubuntu1, automatic), libigdgmm11:i386 (20.1.1+ds1-1, automatic), libgpg-error0:i386 (1.37-1, automatic), libwrap0:i386 (7.6.q-30, automatic), libavahi-common-data:i386 (0.7-4ubuntu7.1, automatic), libjq1:amd64 (1.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libgmp10:i386 (2:6.2.0+dfsg-4, automatic), python-wxgtk3.0:amd64 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1, automatic), libavahi-common3:i386 (0.7-4ubuntu7.1, automatic), libvdpau1:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2, automatic), libncurses6:i386 (6.2-0ubuntu2, automatic), libmp3lame0:i386 (3.100-3, automatic), libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxcursor1:i386 (1:1.2.0-2, automatic), libnuma1:i386 (2.0.12-1, automatic), libk5crypto3:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1, automatic), mesa-utils:amd64 (8.4.0-1build1, automatic), libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5:amd64 (3.0.4+dfsg-15build1, automatic), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1, automatic), libsasl2-2:i386 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), libstb0:i386 (0.0~git20190817.1.052dce1-1, automatic), libxcb-render0:i386 (1.14-2, automatic), libwavpack1:i386 (5.2.0-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libncursesw6:i386 (6.2-0ubuntu2, automatic), libgudev-1.0-0:i386 (1:233-1, automatic), vdpau-driver-all:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2, automatic), libopus0:i386 (1.3.1-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libudev1:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb, automatic), libvpx6:i386 (1.8.2-1build1, automatic), libapparmor1:i386 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1, automatic), libsoup2.4-1:i386 (2.70.0-1, automatic), libltdl7:i386 (2.4.6-14, automatic), libaom0:i386 (1.0.0.errata1-3build1, automatic), libodbc1:i386 (2.3.6-0.1build1, automatic), libperl5.30:i386 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2, automatic), libblkid1:i386 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3, automatic), liblqr-1-0:amd64 (0.4.2-2.1, automatic), libexif12:i386 (0.6.21-6ubuntu0.4, automatic), imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4, automatic), libtiff5:i386 (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.2, automatic), libva2:i386 (2.7.0-2, automatic), libsnmp35:i386 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3, automatic), librtmp1:i386 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1, automatic), libxcomposite1:i386 (1:0.4.5-1, automatic), libx264-155:i386 (2:0.155.2917+git0a84d98-2, automatic), p7zip-full:amd64 (16.02+dfsg-7build1, automatic), libsasl2-modules:i386 (2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (1.44.7-2ubuntu4, automatic), libpulse0:i386 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13, automatic), libmpg123-0:i386 (1.25.13-1, automatic), libxvidcore4:i386 (2:1.3.7-1, automatic), libcaca0:i386 (0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2, automatic), librsvg2-2:i386 (2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libxi6:i386 (2:1.7.10-0ubuntu1, automatic), libkrb5support0:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1, automatic), libiec61883-0:i386 (1.2.0-3, automatic), libzvbi0:i386 (0.2.35-17, automatic), libpcre3:i386 (2:8.39-12build1, automatic), libxv1:i386 (2:1.0.11-1, automatic), libvorbisenc2:i386 (1.3.6-2ubuntu1, automatic), libtag1v5:i386 (1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.3ubuntu2, automatic), libcap2:i386 (1:2.32-1, automatic), libmspack0:amd64 (0.10.1-2, automatic), libxinerama1:i386 (2:1.1.4-2, automatic), libspeex1:i386 (1.2~rc1.2-1.1ubuntu1.20.04.1, automatic), libuuid1:i386 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3, automatic), libgdbm6:i386 (1.18.1-5, automatic), libgcrypt20:i386 (1.8.5-5ubuntu1.1, automatic), libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2, automatic), libavcodec58:i386 (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libkeyutils1:i386 (1.6-6ubuntu1, automatic), libselinux1:i386 (3.0-1build2, automatic), liblz4-1:i386 (1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libpcre2-8-0:i386 (10.34-7, automatic), libxrandr2:i386 (2:1.5.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1, automatic), libavutil56:i386 (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libtheora0:i386 (1.1.1+dfsg.1-15ubuntu2, automatic), libsndfile1:i386 (1.0.28-7ubuntu0.1, automatic), libjpeg8:i386 (8c-2ubuntu8, automatic), gstreamer1.0-x:i386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1, automatic), libgomp1:i386 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04, automatic), libwxbase3.0-0v5:amd64 (3.0.4+dfsg-15build1, automatic), libglu1-mesa:i386 (9.0.1-1build1, automatic), wine32:i386 (5.0-3ubuntu1, automatic), libthai0:i386 (0.1.28-3, automatic), libsoxr0:i386 (0.1.3-2build1, automatic), libwebpmux3:i386 (0.6.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libhogweed5:i386 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libfontconfig1:i386 (2.13.1-2ubuntu3, automatic), libasyncns0:i386 (0.8-6, automatic), libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (2.0.10+dfsg1-3, automatic), libdb5.3:i386 (5.3.28+dfsg1-0.6ubuntu2, automatic), libonig5:amd64 (6.9.4-1, automatic), libmagickcore-6.q16-6:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4, automatic), libfaudio0:i386 (20.04-2, automatic), libosmesa6:i386 (21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1, automatic), libmysqlclient21:i386 (8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3, automatic), gsfonts:amd64 (1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.4, automatic), libasound2:i386 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.5, automatic), libasound2-plugins:i386 (1.2.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libgraphite2-3:i386 (1.3.13-11build1, automatic), libgpm2:i386 (1.20.7-5, automatic), libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1, automatic), libcapi20-3:i386 (1:3.27-3, automatic), libvisual-0.4-0:i386 (0.4.0-17, automatic), fonts-wine:amd64 (5.0-3ubuntu1, automatic), libnettle7:i386 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2, automatic), libxdamage1:i386 (1:1.1.5-2, automatic), libshine3:i386 (3.1.1-2, automatic), cabextract:amd64 (1.9-3, automatic), libjbig0:i386 (2.1-3.1build1, automatic), intel-media-va-driver:i386 (20.1.1+dfsg1-1, automatic), libxml2:i386 (2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libflac8:i386 (1.3.3-1build1, automatic), icoutils:amd64 (0.32.3-3, automatic), libgnutls30:i386 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.6, automatic), libroken18-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libpcap0.8:i386 (1.9.1-3, automatic), libtwolame0:i386 (0.4.0-2, automatic), libfreetype6:i386 (2.10.1-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), libgsm1:i386 (1.0.18-2, automatic), libva-x11-2:i386 (2.7.0-2, automatic), libcodec2-0.9:i386 (0.9.2-2, automatic), libp11-kit0:i386 (0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libva-drm2:i386 (2.7.0-2, automatic), libxpm4:i386 (1:3.5.12-1, automatic), libnetpbm10:amd64 (2:10.0-15.3build1, automatic), mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1, automatic), ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (2.2.11-1ubuntu1, automatic), libvorbis0a:i386 (1.3.6-2ubuntu1, automatic), libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10, automatic), libv4l-0:i386 (1.18.0-2build1, automatic), libharfbuzz0b:i386 (2.6.4-1ubuntu4, automatic), libtasn1-6:i386 (4.16.0-2, automatic), libv4lconvert0:i386 (1.18.0-2build1, automatic), libpci3:i386 (1:3.6.4-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 (1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.3ubuntu2, automatic), libgdbm-compat4:i386 (1.18.1-5, automatic), wine:amd64 (5.0-3ubuntu1, automatic), i965-va-driver:i386 (2.4.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), libcairo2:i386 (1.16.0-4ubuntu1, automatic), liblzma5:i386 (5.2.4-1ubuntu1, automatic), libavc1394-0:i386 (0.5.4-5, automatic), libavahi-client3:i386 (0.7-4ubuntu7.1, automatic), curl:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7, automatic), libpango-1.0-0:i386 (1.44.7-2ubuntu4, automatic), libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxss1:i386 (1:1.2.3-1, automatic), libxkbcommon0:i386 (0.10.0-1, automatic), libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (1.16.2-2, automatic), libsamplerate0:i386 (0.1.9-2, automatic), libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4, automatic), python-wxversion:amd64 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1, automatic), libgpg-error-l10n:amd64 (1.37-1, automatic), libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7, automatic), libsane:i386 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2, automatic), playonlinux:amd64 (4.3.4-1ubuntu1), libfribidi0:i386 (1.0.8-2, automatic), libwine:i386 (5.0-3ubuntu1, automatic), mesa-va-drivers:i386 (21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1, automatic), libxslt1.1:i386 (1.1.34-4, automatic), imagemagick-6-common:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4, automatic), libdatrie1:i386 (0.2.12-3, automatic), libwayland-cursor0:i386 (1.18.0-1, automatic), libslang2:i386 (2.3.2-4, automatic), libpng16-16:i386 (1.6.37-2, automatic)
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb), libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.15, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15pop0~1642720691~20.04~baa7bbb)
End-Date: 2022-03-01  19:05:34

Start-Date: 2022-03-01  19:09:42
Commandline: apt install lutris
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: lutris:amd64 (0.5.9.1~ubuntu20.04.1), python3-html5lib:amd64 (1.0.1-2, automatic), winetricks:amd64 (0.0+20200412-1, automatic), python3-webencodings:amd64 (0.5.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libvkd3d1:amd64 (1.1-4, automatic), python3-setproctitle:amd64 (1.1.10-1ubuntu1, automatic), fuseiso:amd64 (20070708-3.2build1, automatic), libstb0:amd64 (0.0~git20190817.1.052dce1-1, automatic), python3-magic:amd64 (2:0.4.15-3, automatic), python3-evdev:amd64 (1.3.0+dfsg-1build1, automatic), libwine-development:amd64 (5.5-3ubuntu1, automatic), libfaudio0:amd64 (20.04-2, automatic), python3-soupsieve:amd64 (1.9.5+dfsg-1, automatic), fluid-soundfont-gm:amd64 (3.1-5.1, automatic), fluid-soundfont-gs:amd64 (3.1-5.1, automatic), python3-lxml:amd64 (4.5.0-1ubuntu0.5, automatic), python3-bs4:amd64 (4.8.2-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-03-01  19:09:59

Start-Date: 2022-03-02  06:05:02
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7), libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7), libc6:i386 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7)
End-Date: 2022-03-02  06:05:06

Start-Date: 2022-03-02  06:05:09
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: locales:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7)
End-Date: 2022-03-02  06:05:30

Start-Date: 2022-03-02  06:05:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libc-bin:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2, 2.31-0ubuntu9.7)
End-Date: 2022-03-02  06:05:34

Start-Date: 2022-03-02  10:54:44
Commandline: packagekit role='install-files'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: libcanberra-gtk-module:amd64 (0.30-7ubuntu1, automatic), configuradorfnmt:amd64 (1.0.1-0), libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 (0.30-7ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-03-02  10:54:49

Start-Date: 2022-03-02  10:56:37
Commandline: packagekit role='install-files'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: libnss3-tools:amd64 (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.6, automatic), autofirma:amd64 (1.7.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-02  10:56:40

Start-Date: 2022-03-02  10:58:12
Commandline: packagekit role='install-files'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: pcscd:amd64 (1.8.26-3, automatic), libpkcs11-dnie:amd64 (1.6.8), pinentry-gtk2:amd64 (1.1.0-3build1, automatic), libccid:amd64 (1.4.31-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-03-02  10:58:17

Start-Date: 2022-03-03  10:04:12
Commandline: packagekit role='remove-packages'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Remove: libnvidia-compute-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-510:i386 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-510:i386 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-510:i386 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-utils-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.8.16~0.20.04.1), nvidia-dkms-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-driver-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.18build1), libnvidia-common-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-extra-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-settings:amd64 (470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3), nvidia-kernel-source-510:amd64 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-03  10:04:26

Start-Date: 2022-03-03  14:04:24
Commandline: apt install python3-pip
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: python3-dev:amd64 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2, automatic), libpython3.8-dev:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2, automatic), libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.2.9-1ubuntu0.2, automatic), python3-pip:amd64 (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6), python3-wheel:amd64 (0.34.2-1, automatic), python3.8-dev:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2, automatic), libpython3-dev:amd64 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2, automatic), python-pip-whl:amd64 (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6, automatic), python3-setuptools:amd64 (45.2.0-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-03-03  14:04:27

Start-Date: 2022-03-03  15:05:11
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Remove: qt5-style-kvantum-l10n:amd64 (1.0.0+repack-1~focal1)
End-Date: 2022-03-03  15:05:11

Start-Date: 2022-03-03  15:31:34
Commandline: packagekit role='install-packages'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-dkms-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-decode-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-encode-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-driver-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-common-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-utils-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-kernel-common-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-compute-utils-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-cfg1-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-extra-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic)
Remove: libnvidia-compute-510:i386 (510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-03  15:32:28

Start-Date: 2022-03-03  15:36:30
Commandline: apt install htop
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: htop:amd64 (2.2.0-2build1)
End-Date: 2022-03-03  15:36:32

Start-Date: 2022-03-06  06:53:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (97.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 97.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-06  06:53:54

Start-Date: 2022-03-06  06:53:58
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (97.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 97.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-06  06:53:58

Start-Date: 2022-03-07  16:30:28
Commandline: packagekit role='remove-packages'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Remove: libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-dkms-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-driver-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-common-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-utils-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-extra-450-server:amd64 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-07  16:30:43

Start-Date: 2022-03-07  16:30:59
Commandline: packagekit role='install-packages'
Requested-By: dan (1000)
Install: libnvidia-compute-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-compute-510:i386 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-encode-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-encode-510:i386 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), nvidia-kernel-common-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-gl-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-gl-510:i386 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-decode-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-decode-510:i386 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-cfg1-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), nvidia-utils-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), nvidia-dkms-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), nvidia-compute-utils-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), nvidia-driver-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec), screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.18build1, automatic), libnvidia-common-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), libnvidia-extra-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic), nvidia-settings:amd64 (470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3, automatic), nvidia-kernel-source-510:amd64 (510.54-1pop0~1645719405~20.04~10b5fec, automatic)
Remove: libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386 (450.172.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-03-07  16:32:02
```

Comment: Did you installed Nvidia drivers? If not, there's your answer.

Comment: If the problem went away with a clean installation and then new problems started after you made a bunch of customizations, then maybe the problem is whatever you are doing to customize your system. Can you be more specific about what you did? By your own account you are new to Ubuntu, so if you changed the OS beyond what is available in the default system settings, then it's likely that you broke something

Comment: @Nmath The reinstallation solved the "internet problem". Along the way the OP reports customizations, etc. but not the OBS streaming working or not prior the first usage in the new installation. So, we don't know and can't know if it's related or not. My money is on the absence of proper drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm not sure how to install the drivers I need, but I've switched between X.Org and the newest Nvidia drivers that pop in the Additional Drivers section of Software & Updates, with little success.  Right now I have it on nvidia-driver-510-server (proprietary)

Comment: So, if you have the recommended Nvdia drivers (AKA tested), do you? And you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI you have the ideal conditions for the hardware. You may want to re-check either condition.

Comment: @Nmath I tried clarifying in an edit with a log I found, I don't know if it will be helpful..

Comment: @ChanganAuto Done and done, I got the newest Nvidia driver (510 proprietary) and Secure Boot is disabled in UEFI